# Is there a way to hide the ugly SIM Tool Kit icon from the launcher?

Tags: launcher, uninstallation, app-icons

The SIM Tool Kit icon is ugly and app is one that I never used. Unfortunately, I've read that it is one of those system apps that cannot be removed so I'd like to simply hide the icon from my launcher.

I'm using the Google Launcher and not running any XPosed mods.

Answer (score 1):

In NOVA launcher it is simple.
**Settings / Menu / Hide applications**

This will hide it in the app drawer.

Comment: Can you explain what is NOVA launcher and how to install it?

Comment: [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher), [Nova Launcher Prime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime)

Comment: @peter.zrn You can [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/106992/edit) your answer and fill the details from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found two approaches through a quick Google search:

1. **No Root access required**: Google Launcher doesn't offer any feature to change or hide an app icon. The compromise is to use altogether a different launcher such as [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) (mentioned by *peter.zm*), [Action Launcher 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionlauncher.playstore), etc. I personally prefer [SmartLauncher 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ginlemon.flowerfree) app. You tap and hold the app, choose **hide** and done for good.

   I have heard of icon packs that can be integrated into Android with no need for root access but they mostly replace all the device's apps icons.
2. **Root Access required**: If your device is rooted, the possibilities seems endless. There is an app named [Unicon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sg.ruqqq.IconThemer) which claims to customize icons and can work with stock launcher (should work with Google Now too). Another app is an Xposed module named [Xposed GEL Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.theknut.xposedgelsettings) which can hide the icons *et al.*